# My Morse code program won't work in a 2D array, is there another way to do it?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, python-3.7, morse-code

I am trying to make a program in python to learn Morse code, I've been trying to use a 2D array to store the letters and their Morse version.

It is quite long so I will just show you what it looks like with a and b:

`morse_letters =[['a','b']['.-','-...']]`

I understand that I cannot use those characters because they are not an integer,  is there any way I can do this with the 2D array or is there another method that would work better?

Sorry if I'm missing anything obvious I'm quite new to learning python, but would love to learn more.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Look up dictionaries in the tutorial of your choice.

Comment: Use a dictionary instead. So, your Morse code will look like a table where keys are characters that point to Morse values

Comment: By the way, there are no _arrays_ in Python, there are tuples and lists. However, a dictionary is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you wanna program but if you are looking for 'array' like structure in python it's List,Dictionary and so on, but for the morse code program i suggest using Dictionary, they are sort of like a 2-D array, with key-value pair.

dict = {'a': '.-','b':'-...', 'c': '-.-.'}

kind of like this....